# My  Access KeyChain certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

i create a provision and  developer identity.certificate with apple provision assistant and i have huge problem , everything done , but when i add my certificate into KeyChain , the certificate add , but doesn't show on the Keys and my Certificate :( and xcode Organizer says

> a valid signing identity matching
>   this profile could not be found in
>   your keychain

and compiler :

> ```
> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any
> ```
>
> valid certificate/private key pair in
>   the default keychain

i didn't have this problem on the leopard with sdk 3.1 my current os is 10.6.2 SDK 3.1.3
what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) link will be useful for you.

All the best.

Comment: NOOOOOOOO , didn't work :( ,, what can i do now ! i need run my app with my device 
my os 10.6.2 and sdk 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Bundle ID matched to the Mobile Provisioning's Bundle ID.

> Xcode Project > Build Setting > Code Signing

If the bundle ID matched, you will see those valid cert will